# TFS 2012 Build Server NUnit Exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, tfs, nunit

I have a NUnit test project that I'm trying to run on my TFS 2012 Build server.
I'm getting the following error:

- Exception System.InvalidOperationException, Exception thrown
  executing tests
- No test is available in C:\Builds\1\Projects\NUNIT
  Test\bin\NUnitTestProject.dll C:\Builds\1\Projects\NUNIT
  Test\bin\NUnitTestProject.dll. Make sure that installed test
  discoverers & executors, platform & framework version settings are
  appropriate and try again.

I Have the NUnit.VisualStudio.TestAdapter 1.1.0.0 installed from NuGet and referenced in the project.

I also have set the *Version control path to custom assemblies* set on the controller, which contains (they basically are a copy of the NuGet package):

nunit.core.dll
nunit.core.interfaces.dll
nunit.util.dll
NUnit.VisualStudio.TestAdapter.dll

For test purposes, I'm only building the NUnit test project.

My test class is very simple and is the following:

```
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace NUnitTestProject
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class MySuperTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void MyFirstUnitTestMethod_ReturnsTrue()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something I haven't done correctly?

**Edit 1:**
Using TFS 2012 Update 4 on my build server

**Edit 2:**
The problem I believe lies in the 1.1.0.X version.
Updating to 1.1.0.7 I did not have the exception anymore, however, I did have the tests not found problem.

There are some issues going on about that on github https://github.com/nunit/nunit-vs-adapter/

**Edit 3:**
The problem has been fixed in 1.1.0.8 of the NUnit test adapter!

Comment: Thanks this helped me out. Version 1.2 works fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your test runner set correctly in the build defiintion?

Image shows TFS2013 but 2012 has a different option for 2010 compatability which may be selected. The Visual Studio Test Runner should support multiple test frameworks, whereas the 2010 compatability one only supports MSTest

[image: Choose Test Runner]

Comment: Yes I am using the visual studio test runner setting.
As seen here: http://imgur.com/6qTJuGz